# create duplicate database on sql server 2008 for testing

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have created a Database on Sql Server 2008 for production, now i want to create duplicate database for testing.

Please give suggestion how to create duplicate database structure and data on localhost.

Answer (score 1):

What about backup database on prod and restore it localy?

Comment: How to restore database from backup database file.